# jPlayer - how to find out if it's playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

How can I find out if jPlayer is playing?
I tried this `alert($.jPlayer.event.playing);` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi.. same questions apply here - which browser, media, solution, constructor options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kyle's method works fine, here's a fiddle to demonstrate it in action: 
http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/95EPu/

However, ordinarily you wouldn't need to access jPlayer's internals like this, being an event-driven plugin.. would it be cleaner to respond to one of jPlayer's many events (at the appropriate moment)? 
http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-events

Comment: I copied whole code from the result from JSFiddle but it doesn't work in my separate file http://dev.podlipsky.net/ (some css are missing but it doesn't matter). I don't understand why because the code is same and paths are absolute

Comment: @simPod It looks like it is working. What browser do you use?

Comment: I'm getting 'true' no matter what. Even when I use `$('#player').jPlayer("play").data().jPlayer.status.paused`. Any help?

Answer (score 16):

I've not worked with Jplayer specifically, but playing around, this returned false if the media was playing and true if it wasn't.

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_1').data().jPlayer.status.paused
```

Comment: that's weird :/ it gives me `("#jquery_jplayer").data().jPlayer.status is undefined`. There must be something wrong with my player. In some other cases it returns `$.jPlayer.event is undefined`...

Comment: I'm sure the missing '$' in your comment was an accident, just make sure you're pointing that to the ID of the DIV you're targeting jPlayer at

Comment: Looking at this and your other question, I'm starting to think that you have the wrong selector

Comment: it was an accident, it's like `alert($('#jquery_jplayer').data().jPlayer.status.paused);`. I don't think it's wrong selector, I created jPlayer like this `$("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({...})`. It's the same selector... That's rly weird

Comment: Then you're calling `alert($('#jquery_jplayer').data().jPlayer.status.paused);` AFTER the jPlayer is initiated, right?

Comment: @simPod  Try this `$('#jquery_jplayer').data('jPlayer').status.paused`

Comment: @Kyle Macey yea, I'm calling it in onClick event, it's already initialized there...

Answer (score 0):

On my setup, I noticed the class "jp-state-playing" was added to the div that included jp-audio.  I have not done a lot of research, but querying for a null object or not seemed better than tying myself to jPlayers internals.

Comment: Unfortunately, the container's `.jp-state-playing` class is removed when the player is paused.

Answer (score 0):

```
var duration = $('#jquery_jplayer_1').data("jPlayer").status.currentTime;

if(duration){
  // Source is loaded and playing 
}
```

Comment: Hi there, code-only answers often get flagged for moderation. Why does this work? Please add a little explanation. Cheers!